# Creating TicTacToe using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, json, tic-tac-toe

I am creating a TicTacToe game, yet I keep getting a syntax error at the end of my code. The game is not finished but could anyone explain why I am getting the following error? The problem is that the syntax error is being displayed right after the last line, which doesn't contain what it is referring about. Any modifications and changes would be helpful.

```
    /tmp/source.js:160
    });
     ^

    SyntaxError: Unexpected token )
        at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
        at Module._compile (module.js:373:25)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
        at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
        at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:441:10)
        at startup (node.js:139:18)
        at node.js:968:3`
```

```js
// start of evaluation code
process.stdin.resume();
process.stdin.setEncoding('utf8');

var stdin = '';
process.stdin.on('data', function (chunk) {
    addResultToStdin(chunk);
}).on('end', function() {
    var lines = stdin.split('\n');
    for(var i=0; i<lines.length; i++) {
        process.stdout.write(lines[i]);
    }
});

function addResultToStdin(chunk) {
        var output = '';
        var instructions = chunk.split('|');
        var method = instructions[0];
        tictactoe.reset();
        for (var i = 1; i < instructions.length; i++) {
                if(instructions[i] === 'undo') {
                        if(i === instructions.length - 1) {
                                output += JSON.stringify(tictactoe.undo());
                        } else {
                                tictactoe.undo();
                        }
                } else {
                        var moves = instructions[i].split(',');
                        var x = moves[0].trim();
                        var y = moves[1].trim();
                        if(i === instructions.length - 1) {
                                output += JSON.stringify(tictactoe[method](x, y));
                        } else {
                                tictactoe[method](x, y);
                        }
                }
        }
        stdin += output;
}

function TicTacToe() {
        this.init();
}

TicTacToe.prototype.getCurrentState = function() {
        this.state = TicTacToe.prototype.updatedBoard

TicTacToe.prototype.reset = function() {
        this.init();
};

TicTacToe.prototype.init = function() {
        this.state = [];
       // setting initial state
        this.state.push({
                activePlayer: 'x',
                currentBoard: this.freshBoard()
        });
};

TicTacToe.prototype.updatedBoard = function(x,y) {
        var state = this.getCurrentState();
        var activePlayer = state.activePlayer;
        var currentBoard = state.currentBoard;
        var newBoard = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < currentBoard.length; i++) {
                newBoard.push(currentBoard[i].concat());
        }
        newBoard[x][y] = activePlayer;
        return newBoard;
};

TicTacToe.prototype.freshBoard = function() {
        return [
                [null, null, null],
                [null, null, null],
                [null, null, null]
        ];
};

TicTacToe.prototype.undo = function() {
        activePlayer = ( activePlayer === 'x' ) ? 'o' : 'x';
        return state.currentBoard;
};

TicTacToe.prototype.isValidTurn = function(x, y) {
       if ( TicTacToe.prototype.freshBoard == 
                [null, null, null],
                [null, null, null],
                [null, null, null] ) {
          return true;
        } else {
          alert( 'Select a blank space my friend.' );
          return false;
        }
};

TicTacToe.prototype.isWinningTurn = function(activePlayer, updatedBoard) {
        var checkVertical = function () {
                for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++){
                    var sum = this.state[i][0] + this.state[i][1] + this.state[i][2];
                    if (sum === 3 || sum === -3){
                        return true
                    }
                }
                return false;
        };
        var checkHorizontal = function () {
            for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++){
                var sum = this.results[0][i] + this.results[1][i] + this.results[2][i];
                if (sum === 3 || sum === -3){
                    return true
                }
            }
                return false;
        };
        var checkDiagonal = function () {
            for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++){
                var sum = this.results[i][i] + this.results[i+1][i+1] + this.results[i+2][i+2];
                if (sum === 3 || sum === -3){
                    return true
                }
            }
                return false;
        };

        if(checkDiagonal() || checkHorizontal() || checkVertical()) {
                return true;
        }
        return false;
};
TicTacToe.prototype.takeTurn = function(x, y) {
        var state = this.getCurrentState();
        var valid = false;
        var winning = false;
        if(this.isValidTurn(x, y)) {
                var newState = {
                        activePlayer: (state.activePlayer === 'x') ? 'o' : 'x'
                };
                valid = true;
                newState.currentBoard = this.updatedBoard(x, y);
                newState.winningMove = winning = this.isWinningTurn(state.activePlayer, newState.currentBoard);
                this.state.push(newState);
        }
        return {
                board: newState.currentBoard,
                moveBy: state.activePlayer,
                valid: valid,
                winning: winning
        };
}
var tictactoe = new TicTacToe();
```

Comment: you're not closing this --> TicTacToe.prototype.getCurrentState = function() {
        this.state = TicTacToe.prototype.updatedBoard

Comment: Aw man:/ thanks a ton! That had me stuck for a minute. Any other help mistakes you see, please don't hesitate to point out! Thanks again on the swift reply.

Answer (score 1):

```
TicTacToe.prototype.getCurrentState = function() {
    this.state = TicTacToe.prototype.updatedBoard
```

Missing ending `}`